# Installing SQL Server 2014 RS Add-ins for SharePoint 2013 in Multiple Server Farms

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I am currently working with a multiple-servers SharePoint Farm (1 Database server, 1 Web Front End server, and 1 Application Server), and I have already installed SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services Add-ins for SharePoint 2013 on the WFE Server and Application Server.

The SQL Server which I've installed on the DB server also already had the Reporting Services Add-ins for SharePoint Products feature activated. I've also already run the PowerShell commands.

```
Install-SPRSService
Install-SPRSServiceProxy
```

But when I tried to create a new SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application from the Manage Service Applications at the Central Administration, I got the following error:

> Installation Error: Could not find SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120 registry key.

Are there anything wrong with my installation steps? I've tried to google for some solutions, mostly stated that I need to install the RS add-ins on all Application server, which I've already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware of downloading and installing [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=42294) didn't create `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120` registry key.

So It's heavily recommended to install the `Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint` from the SQL Server 2014 Media (.ISO), and make sure that you have checked the `Reporting Service Add-In For SharePoint Products.` as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I have already check that feature (Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint products) when I installed SQL Server 2014 on the Database Server. Or could I install that feature only on the WFE Server and App Server?

Comment: yes install that feature only on the WFE Server and App Server

Comment: You need to install RS add in on WFE.